# AWS Application Load Balancer and Nginx Reverse Proxy issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx-reverse-proxy

We have setup an Application Load Balancer and behind it we have setup an ec2 instance with Nginx. The Nginx has been configured to serve as reverse proxy for NodeJS application which is configured on another instance. We use web socket in our application and hence we need Application Load Balancer. Now the problem is that the https traffic is redirected from the Load Balancer to the Nginx server. However, the Nginx server does not connect to the NodeJS instance and instead directly sends a 301 response to the ALB. The ALB in return sends another request to the Nginx which in return sends 301 response resulting in redirect loop. We have checked the Nginx configuration and did not find any issue. What could be the problem here?